# Angualrjs ng-src async image loading from a function call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I am wondering if it's possible to assign a result of a function call to an ng-src in an image?

Basically, I need to retrieve a set of thumbnails for a set of data from an aspx page, there may or may not be a thumbnail. So I need to show a different preset image for a case when there is nothing returned from the thumbnail page.

Something like this:

```
<img ng-src="getThumbnail({{ item.Id }})" />
```

Where getThumbnail is a function which makes a http request to a url such as

```
http://localhost/Srv/getThumbnail.aspx?id=111
```

I've tried this but Angular is producing this:

```
<img ng-src="getThumbnail(111)" src="getThumbnail(111)">
```

Instead of calling the function. Is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `{{getThumbnail(item.id)}}`? Assuming the `getThumbnail` function is also in a reachable scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've commented on your question but I'll offer my suggestion as a solution after looking at the AngularJS documentation. The [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive will correctly set the `src` attribute of `img`. This directive can contain Angular [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and these can call functions contained in your controller and reachable in the current scope. Hence instead of:

```
<img ng-src="getThumbnail({{ item.Id }})" />
```

Try this:

```
<img ng-src="{{ getThumbnail(item.Id) }}" />
```

In the former declaration, the function isn't available to the Angular scope, but it is in the latter. (If I am not mistaken, as I haven't tried the code myself).

Make sure the `getThumbnail` function is in a controller that is reachable to the current scope.

Comment: I know this is a bit off topic, but would it be possible to use a similar method for async loading of ng-options in a select?

Comment: @streetlight no sorry